# How to assign string from array to a char to get the length of the string?

Tags: c, arrays

Ok I am in the process of making a simple hangman game.  I need help pulling a string which is in an array `dict[num]` num being a random number.  I just need a way to get that string out and use `strlen()` and such functions to work with it.

As of now `strlen(dict[num])` does not work?

Comment: At a minimum, you probably need to show the declaration of `dict`.

Comment: Why do you need `strlen` when you have `num`?

Comment: Paul R, you are right but that method of `strlen(dict[num])` is not working. I am using it like this `len=strlen(dict[num])` and this gives me a segmentation error

Comment: Jueecy, num is the index of the word in an array containing all of the words.  I know this is wasteful in mem but it is how we were told to do it.

Comment: Do you get any compiler warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the type of the dict array is char then to get the length

```
strlen(dict)
```

and not

```
strlen(dict[num])
```

and if the

```
strlen(dict)
```

gives segmentation error then chek that your array is filled with string I mean check the string in the array end with the null character `'\0'`